Journey Sends Past 30 Days shows a journey name of N/A
I have an automated report that runs for the journeys 30 day send and everytime it runs it gives me this
Journey Name    Email Sends
N/A              144130
Thats a lot of sends for a journey name N/A. Looking at my journeys I dont see any named N/a. Any one know why its doing this or what I can do to fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There might be an issue with how the report is generating or pulling data, particularly if it's showing "N/A" for the Journey Name. You can follow some steps to troubleshoot further.

If you are using data views and dataextension to generate the report then I would recommedn to validate this first in Query Studio and ensure that that the journey names are correctly populated in the relevant extensions

Review the SQL query or data logic used in the automated report(SQL query). Make sure that the query is correctly joining the necessary dataviews or dataextension and that there are no issues with how it retrieves and aggregates data.


